# I'm getting "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

As I understood when I send the response the register function doesn't end ! I tried to put return with res and still have the same problem !

```
const connection = require("../../db");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");


const register = (req, res) => {

    const { user_name, password, phone, email } = req.body;
    const role_id = 0;
    var dateObj = new Date();
    const month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    const day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    const year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
    const created_at = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
    const is_disabled = 0

    // Cheacking if there is no email or user name in the database.
    let query = `SELECT * from users WHERE email = '${email}' OR user_name ='${user_name}' `;
    connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result.length) {
            if (email === result[0].email) {
                return res.json("Email is already used.")
                
            } else {
                return res.json("User name is already used.")
            };
        };
    });
    //Hashing the password.
    const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, Number(process.env.SALT), (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err
    });

    // Adding new user to database.
    query = `insert INTO users (email,phone,password,user_name,role_id,created_at,is_disabled) VALUES('${email}','${phone}','${hashPassword}','${user_name}','${role_id}','${created_at}','${is_disabled}')`
    connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err
    })
    return res.json("Added user")
}
module.exports = register
```

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use string interpolation to inject data, always use *placeholder values*. This has severe SQL injection bugs.

Comment: you have potentially two `res.json()` statements happening ... `res.json("Email is already used.")` or `res.json("User name is already used.")` AND then `res.json("Added user")` - the `return` statements for those first to `res.json` do not *terminate* the `register` function, they simply *terminate* the current callback function

Comment: @tadman my teacher told me to do that , but he didn't told me why , now I got it thx

Comment: I would put everything from `//Hashing the password.` and on inside an `else` for the `if (result.length) {` statement .... i.e. `if (result.length) { .... blah blah } else { //Hashing the password. etc }` (actually, it doesn't have to be inside an else at all, since you `return` in the `if`) .... so ... move everything from `//Hashing the password.` until the end of that function up inside the `});` above that line

Comment: @JaromandaX WORKED thx <3

Comment: I agree with @Jaromanda X, i/o task(include network and database task, disk i/o task) in node.js is asynchronous, you should use async/await to void the problem.

Comment: Another thing to note is the error handling for a failed Bcrypt is basically junk. Throwing an exception inside a callback doesn't properly bubble up, it just crashes out randomly later. If you're doing callback code you can't use `throw`, you must call back with the `err` you're given, pass it back up the chain.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the password hashing/new user code inside the callback since these must happen only after the email/username checks are already done. Otherwise, you'll asynchronously be checking for conflicts *and* creating the account; potentially resulting in trying to send multiple responses back to the client.

```js
const register = (req, res) => {

    const { user_name, password, phone, email } = req.body;
    const role_id = 0;
    var dateObj = new Date();
    const month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    const day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    const year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
    const created_at = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
    const is_disabled = 0

    // Cheacking if there is no email or user name in the database.
    let query = `SELECT * from users WHERE email = '${email}' OR user_name ='${user_name}' `;
    connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result.length) {
            if (email === result[0].email) {
                return res.json("Email is already used.")
                
            } else {
                return res.json("User name is already used.")
            };
        };

        //Hashing the password.
        const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, Number(process.env.SALT), (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err
        });

        // Adding new user to database.
        query = `insert INTO users (email,phone,password,user_name,role_id,created_at,is_disabled) VALUES('${email}','${phone}','${hashPassword}','${user_name}','${role_id}','${created_at}','${is_disabled}')`
        connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err
        })
        return res.json("Added user")
    });
}
```